# Manipulating list of dictionary in a single line list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list like below:

```
l = [{'Value': 'value1', 'Key': 'key1'}, {'Value': 'value2', 'Key': 'key2'}, {'Value': 'value3', 'Key': 'key3'}]
```

I want a output list as below:

```
lst = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]
```

My code is as below:

```
lst = []
for item in l:
    key = item["Key"]
    value = item["Value"]
    dict = {}
    dict[key] = value
    lst.append(dict)
```

Is it possible to do the same in a single line with list comprehension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
l = [{'Value': 'value1', 'Key': 'key1'}, {'Value': 'value2', 'Key': 'key2'}, {'Value': 'value3', 'Key': 'key3'}]

>>> [{item['Key']: item['Value']} for item in l]
[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]
```